# Is this example of scaling fractions correct?

Tags: arithmetic, fractions

Suppose we have $\frac{5\times2}{3\times5}$.

If we consider it as $\frac{5}{5}\times\frac{2}{3}$, then $\frac{5}{5}$ is being scaled down and $\frac{2}{3}$ is neither being scaled down, nor being scaled up.

Now, if we consider it as $\frac{5}{3}\times\frac{2}{5}$ or $\frac{2}{5}\times\frac{5}{3}$, then $\frac{5}{3}$ is being scaled down and $\frac{2}{5}$ is being scaled up.

Is the above example correct?

Comment: You can consider either of the fractions a scaling factor with the other the thing being scaled. That's fine. But it does not really make sense to me to think of them doing it simultaneously to the other.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Yes, but just for understanding the example is correct, right?

Comment: Yes. A scaling factor smaller than one scales something down, makes it smaller, while a factor greater than one scales something up, makes it larger.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Got it, thanks for the help

Comment: @Steve,Even if your doubt was resolved,You must understand that The scaling of both fractions in single number is not interpreted to occur simultaneously,**Either** first is being scaled up by other factor **or** the other is being scaled down by first one